# Is it possible for GFE to use a managed certs to establish TLS with mesh ingress on GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-anthos-service-mesh

I'm trying ASM(Anthos Service Mesh) to create a service mesh in the GKE.

I'm looking at the following steps, but do we need to use a self-signed certificate here?

> In the following steps, you generate and install a certificate (as a Kubernetes secret resource) that enables the GFE to establish a TLS connection to the service mesh's ingress gateway.
> https://cloud.google.com/architecture/exposing-service-mesh-apps-through-gke-ingress/deployment#install_the_self-signed_ingress_gateway_certificate

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
    name: asm-ingressgateway
    namespace: asm-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    asm: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - "*" # IMPORTANT: Must use wildcard here when using SSL, see note below
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: edge2mesh-credential # <- HERE
```

It would be easier to manage if I could replace it with the GKE ManagedCertificate or the GCP Managed SSL Certificate.

The GKE mode is autopilot, so we can't use ASM Gateway. It seems ASM Gateway can use `networking.gke.io/pre-shared-certs: $GCP_COMPUTE_MANAGED_SSL_CERTIFICATE`.

ref:
https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/managed/service-mesh-cloud-gateway

Comment: Even with ASM Gateway, the pre-shared cert is actually being used to configure the load balancer and not the actual ingress gateway.